# Manipulate json data with unnamed fields on klipfolio - google api

Tags: json, xml, xpath, adsense, klipfolio

I use Klipfolio as a dashboard to show my KPIs on adsense. I used Google API to fetch all my data in a json format. 
My dimensions are: date, ad unit.
My metric is: earnings.
I want to create a graph that shows a breakdwown earnings per ad unit AND per date.
In my json results I have 3 unnamed rows: for the date, for the ad unit name, and for the earnings. 
I want to go fetch elements in row 3 `(kf:element_at(rows,3) )` BUT only if preceded by my ad unit. so it should look like this:

```
kf:element_at(rows,3[preceding-sibling::2='ad test home page']/*)
```

But I am not sure of how to write it ... and also i want to match with the x-axis (date) :/ Can you please help me ?